# Unity3D C# abstract class with static instance creation not working

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine, types

Hello I am working on a objectpooling class has T "ObjectPooling".
And made a child class. So I want to make automatic singleton for this class. So if I use "instance" it should check if m_instance is null. If yes "spawn" the script and assign m_instance.

```
public abstract class ObjectPooling<T> : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static float start = 30;
    public static bool extendable = true;

    public List<T> objects = new List<T>();

    public abstract T getNext();
    public abstract void Add(T obj);

    static T m_instance;
    public static T instance
    {
        get
        {
            return m_instance ?? (m_instance = CreateInstance());
        }
    }

    protected static T CreateInstance()
    {

        GameObject g = new GameObject("ObjectPooling");
        var c = g.AddComponent<T>();
        return c;
    }
}
```

The problem is at the last lines in the CreateInstance().
It says

> An implicitly typed local variable declaration cannot be initialized
>   with `UnityEngine.GameObject.AddComponent(System.Type)'

I am not sure what can I do here now. I tried with ObjectPooling before but thats gives no error but also is not working.

So my goal is that the child has also singleton. I did it currently manually but want I want to later should be like this (ofc the base class should do it instead of child class but still check it).

```
public class BulletPooling : ObjectPooling<BulletBase>  
{
    public override void Add(BulletBase obj)
    {
        if(extendable)
            objects.Add(obj);
    }

    public override BulletBase getNext()
    {

        for(int i = 0; i < objects.Count; i++)
        {
            var bs = objects[i];
            if (!bs.gameObject.activeInHierarchy)
                return bs;
        }


        return null;
    }

    // this part
    static BulletPooling m_instance;
    public static BulletPooling instance
    {
        get
        {
            return m_instance ?? (m_instance = CreateInstance());
        }
    }

    protected static BulletPooling CreateInstance()
    {

        GameObject g = new GameObject("ObjectPooling");
        var c = g.AddComponent<BulletPooling>();
        return c;
    }
}
```

You can see here I am working with new Childclass which has T = BulletBase

Answer (score 1):

This is because `GameObject.AddComponent` requires an object of a specific type, rather than "any type". In your `ObjectPooling` class, you only specify that it can be an object of any type, and the compiler cannot infer which types you are using beforehand.

`AddComponent` is kind of a nasty function, since you can also pass it a string, which should be the name of a script class.

You could specify the type that `T` must adhere to as `UnityEngine.Component` to get around this. that would look like this :

```
public abstract class ObjectPooling<T>: MonoBehaviour where T : UnityEngine.Component 
{

    public static float start = 30;
    public static bool extendable = true;

    public List<T> objects = new List<T>();

    public abstract T getNext();
    public abstract void Add(T obj);

    static T m_instance;
    public static T instance
    {
        get
        {
            return m_instance ?? (m_instance = CreateInstance());
        }
    }

    protected static T CreateInstance()
    {

        GameObject g = new GameObject("ObjectPooling");
        //this is where your compiler could not tell if T was the correct type by the way...
        var c = g.AddComponent<T>(); 
        return c;
    }
}
```

but that might break the functionality of adding scripts as game components using a string with their name. (though i think in your case, it won't be a problem)

Comment: Oh you are right. Totally forgot it. I see. But I guess I made there a big  mistake. I wanted to get the instance of the child class like to use later "BulletPooling.instance.getNext()" but if I hover over instance now it shows me "BulletBase ObjectPooling<BulletBase>.instance { get; } which is wrong. It should be "BulletPooling BulletPooling .instance { get; }". Hmm I think I need a rework there. I am not sure if this would work